getSignaturesForAddress not fetching some signatures
Token contract: 6ogzHhzdrQr9Pgv6hZ2MNze7UrzBMAFyBBWUYp1Fhitx
I am trying to fetch history of transfers for this token.
My request:
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getSignaturesForAddress",
    "params": [
        "6ogzHhzdrQr9Pgv6hZ2MNze7UrzBMAFyBBWUYp1Fhitx",
        {
            "before":"3LuEcMhbSAgdJJrNRG97GpfQH2wWLo3PqfXmrmvz6NnKyBMboWwpjjQeb26u6wjNQfHmrnhxgyd15cDTmwVZdFQu",
            "commitment":"confirmed"
        }
    ]
}

If we filter out signatures with errors, here are 3 closest signatures that we receive in response:
2B7YYTvMJXSeqJCfmFTDRV2cDNH9HfyHApwdNCYqzfwgAE7fiao51gKA8CXYNNe3QECnEW9fJFzFCLL12iqHzhWg
3ma9TbKhDoZkYi7oVWEj7Ku8MGCpWETJtCaUWWht92njJmZtnWG6PZwM8QzaTBUPiHnTxyvb5ujZWEnD6ns2nbd6
3AbVBYo3cWvouWTLM6kr7JLgYJfpYzcpKp8fAWNgdnxudboPGRU8tgKBMXDDjuCMVSVQxzsBQTaT527wqihPHWDP
However, if we check transfer history on something like solscan.io, we will see that there is one signature that is missing:
26kzWS1NBWPYLGEZELEXAMHKGzTQ6LSHKkBHNhyHGKibKSWcGe5LZ2QYgrUEYpwzL8CB5reKA7FYqnyxJui13vYT

Please help me figure out why this signature is missing when I am fetching data using RPC API.

This is a guess, but the token mint account at 6ogzHhzdrQr9Pgv6hZ2MNze7UrzBMAFyBBWUYp1Fhitx isn't required to do a transfer between two token accounts, but solscan may be doing extra indexing to include all transactions for that mint, even though it wasn't included in the transaction. You might want to try the solscan API to see if it returns the extra transactions.
If you look at the missing transaction: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/26kzWS1NBWPYLGEZELEXAMHKGzTQ6LSHKkBHNhyHGKibKSWcGe5LZ2QYgrUEYpwzL8CB5reKA7FYqnyxJui13vYT
You'll see that it doesn't include the 6ogzHhzdrQr9Pgv6hZ2MNze7UrzBMAFyBBWUYp1Fhitx address

Thank you very much for this response. This makes a lot of sense
Do you have any additional tips on what part of transaction data I should look to get more information on what token/tokens were involved in transaction

The mint should be part of the transaction, but it's not always there unfortunately. If you get the full transaction data, however, the token accounts should have their mints reported in it with jsonParsed encoding

Thank you a lot for this. Solana must be hating programmers xD

Most of the protocols are designed for maximum simplicity on-chain, which sometimes makes things harder for downstream usage. Sorry that it's difficult!
